# WP Gutenberg InnerBlocks not saving

Tags: javascript, wordpress, reactjs, wordpress-gutenberg

I created a custom block type called with the wp-cli, it's working, but when I add innerBlocks to it, the innerBlocks display, but don't save or adhere to any other attributes other than template, templateLock and allowedBlocks are all ignored. Also when I define wp.editor.InnerBlocks as a variable, it returns null, but if I include it in the block edit section, it works fine, still doesn't save. Full code:

```
( function( wp ) {

    var registerBlockType = wp.blocks.registerBlockType,
         __ = wp.i18n.__,
         el = wp.element.createElement
       ;  


    registerBlockType( 'adventures/accommodations', {

        title: __( 'Accommodations' ),
        icon: 'admin-multisite',
        category: 'layout',

        supports: {
            html: false, 
            align: true
        },

        attributes: {
        align: {
            type: 'string',
            default: 'full'
        },
        },

        edit: function( props ) {
        var attributes = props.attributes; 

            return [

            el( 'div', {className: props.className,},  
            el( 'h2', {className: 'sub-header'}, 
              'Accommodations'
          ),
          el( wp.editor.InnerBlocks, {
            allowedBlocks: ['core/columns', 'core/column', 'core/paragraph', 'core/gallery'],
            template: [
              ['core/columns', {},[
                ['core/column', {}, [
                  ['core/gallery']
                ]],
                ['core/column', {},[
                  ['core/paragraph', { placeholder: 'Enter short description...' }]
                ]]
              ]]
            ],
            templateLock: 'all'
          }),

        )

            ]
        },


        save: function( props ) {
          var attributes = props.attributes;
          var InnerBlocks = props.innerBlocks 

            return [

            el( 'div', {className: props.className,},  
            el( 'h2', {className: 'sub-header'}, 
              'Accommodations'
          ), 
          el( InnerBlocks.Content ),
        )

            ]
        }


    });

} )(
    window.wp
);
```

Side note, also trying to make the block align full width without block alignment controls, but can't find any documentation on how to do that. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: On save use - el( InnerBlocks.Content, null ) and delete var InnerBlocks = props.innerBlocks